# Comparing properties of templated child classes from base class pointers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, polymorphism

I have a class template that derives from a parent class. I am storing the children in a vector as `Parent*`. I can later use `typeid` to determine if two objects are the same type. What I want to do is compare a property of two objects that are the same type. For simplicity, I have omitted storing the objects in a vector, but the concept is demonstrated below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

class Parent{ public: virtual ~Parent(){}};

template<typename T>
class TypedChild : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~TypedChild(){}
    T getValue() {return mValue;}
private:
    T mValue;
};

int main()
{

  Parent* child1 = new TypedChild<int>();
  Parent* child2 = new TypedChild<float>();

  std::vector<Parent*> objects;
  objects.push_back(child1);
  objects.push_back(child2);

  if(typeid(*(objects[0])) == typeid(*(objects[1])))
      if(objects[0]->getValue() == objects[1]->getValue()) // compiler error: Parent has no member named getValue
          std::cout << "Success";


  return 0;
}
```

Of course in this example I could dynamic_cast to `TypedChild<int>` before calling `getValue()`, but in the real case where the objects are in a vector I don't know their types, I just know that they are the same type so their `getValue()` functions should return the same type and can hence be compared.

Is there any way to do this comparison?

Comment: @BoPersson They are not all the same type. I want to store objects templated on any type in the vector. Then I want to be able to compare two of those objects, only if they are the same type.

Comment: @BoPersson Apparently my simplification did more harm than good! I updated the example to better show the use case. I meant that I know two objects are the same type because I do a type comparison test using `typeid()`.

Comment: @DavidDoria Ah.  I mistook what you were doing.  deleting comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your use case, being able to avoid a `dynamic_cast` will be hard, if not impossible. If you want to get the value of just one object, you'll need to use `dynamic_cast`, such as:

```
Parent* child = ...;

auto typedChild = dynamic_cast<TypedChild*>(child):
if ( typedChild )
{
   int val = typedChild->getValue();
}
```

If you want to compare two objects for equality, the best case scenario is to have a `virtual` `operator==()` function.

```
class Parent
{
   public:

      virtual ~Parent(){}
      virtual bool operator==(Parent const& rhs) const = 0;

};

template<typename T>
class TypedChild : public Parent
{
   public:
      virtual ~TypedChild(){}
      T getValue() {return mValue;}

      virtual bool operator==(Parent const& rhs) const
      {
         auto derivedRHS = dynamic_cast<TypedChild<T> const*>(&rhs);
         if ( !derivedRHS )
         {
            return false;
         }
         return (this->mValue == derivedRHS->mValue);
      }

   private:
      T mValue;
};
```

Comment: I would actually do a typeid check and a static_cast instead of the dynamic_cast, as the equality comparison may slice for comparisons derived from TypedChild<T>.